# What NpgsqlDbType should be used to clear "Can't write CLR type" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, npgsql

I am using PostgreSQL as my database. I have an application that is written in

- ASP.NET
- C#
- WebForms
- Using Npgsql with PostgreSQL

I have table named **tblAppt** in my database, in that table I have a column named **appttime** that column's Data type is **time without time zone**

In pgAdmin4's **Query Tool** if I run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO tblAppt (appttime) VALUES ('00:30:00');
```

The results are:

```
INSERT 0 1 Query returned successfully in 105 msec.
```

Which means the record was added in my table,  in the image you can see I have a row: 
[image]

Now in my web application I have a text box named **txtCustTime**,  in that text box I enter this value **00:30:00**

When I press the submit button I get the following error:

> **System.InvalidCastException** 
> Can't write CLR type System.String with
>   handler type TimeHandler

Here is a snippet of what happens on the submit:

```
string insertstmt = "INSERT INTO tblAppt(appttime) VALUES (@ApptTime)";
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand (insertstmt, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApptTime", NpgsqlDbType.Time );
cmd.Parameters ["@ApptTime"].Value = txtCustTime.Text;
con.Open ();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery (); 
con.Close ();
```

My question is do I need to cast it because the values in a textbox or use a different datatype, or something else.

**PLEASE NOTE:** *I have other columns in that table that are not time or dates and they submit fine. My problem seems to be specifically to this particular column type.* 

**Additional NOTE:** 
If I run this on submit the value is added to the database:

```
string insertstmt = "INSERT INTO tblAppt(appttime) VALUES ('00:30:00')";
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand (insertstmt, con);
con.Open ();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery (); 
con.Close ();
```

Which tells me my problem I am not understanding has something to do with the parameter.

Comment: have you tried using `TimeSpan` ?

Comment: As documented [here](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/datetime.html): `TimeSpan`

Comment: Doing this NpgsqlDbType.TimeSpan  produced a build error 'Does not contain a definition for TimeSpan'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folks in the comments were correct in that **TimeSpan** is the way to go. However the documentation was not very clear on how to use it.

The correct way to use **TimeSpan** for the problem above is:

```
string insertstmt = "INSERT INTO tblAppt(appttime) VALUES (@ApptTime)"; 
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand (insertstmt, con);
TimeSpan thetime = TimeSpan.Parse(txtCustTime.Text);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApptTime", NpgsqlDbType.Time ); 
cmd.Parameters["@ApptTime"].Value = thetime; 
con.Open (); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery (); 
con.Close ();
```

I used this link as a reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 3):

This is unrelated to your specific issue, but since this post came up as the first result when I was looking for an answer, I thought to provide this additional insight.

I found this same error using Npgsql's bulk copy.  The specific error was:

> "Can't write CLR type System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime] to database type date"

This was the code:

```
using (var writer = conn.BeginBinaryImport("copy table1 from STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)"))
{
    foreach (OcieHeader record in Records)
    {
        writer.StartRow();
        if (record.OrderDate == null)
            writer.WriteNull();
        else
            writer.Write(record.OrderDate, NpgsqlDbType.Date);
    }
}
```

It turns out the type mismatch occurred because I was using a nullable -- it created a type mismatch between `System.DateTime?` (aka `Nullable<DateTime>`) and `NpgsqlDbType.Date`.

Eliminating the nullable .NET type fixed the issue, so the corrected code is:

```
writer.Write(record.OrderDate.Value, NpgsqlDbType.Date);
```

(added `.Value`).