# C# with Npgsql - Can't write CLR type System.String with handler type Int32Handler

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

i have problem when im trying to add integer to Postgresql database. Varchars works fine, but when i use code:

```
var parameter = cmd.CreateParameter();
parameter.Value = Int32.Parse(x.Value.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(parameter.Value);
parameter.ParameterName = x.Key.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("confirmations",NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
for (int search=0; search != cmd.Parameters.Count; search++)
```

error in executing, where im using:

```
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

sounds like:

> Database problem: System.InvalidCastException: Can't write CLR type System.String with handler type Int32Handler\
>
> at lambda_method(Closure , NpgsqlTypeHandler , Object , NpgsqlLengthCache& , NpgsqlParameter )
>
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter.ValidateAndGetLength() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlParameter.cs:line 553
>
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ValidateParameters() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 793
>
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1141
>
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1042
>
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1025
>
> at BitcoinType.DatabaseManager.MakeInsert(Dictionary`2 requestData) in /Users/kamilkostrzewski/Projects/BitcoinType/BitcoinType/Program.cs:line 261

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51877868/what-npgsqldbtype-should-be-used-to-clear-cant-write-clr-type-error) did not helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem and I solved like this. In my database I have a column that type Integer. If you want to add data this column, You should use  **NpgsqlDbType.Integer** datatype. But  when I use **NpgsqlDbType.String** datatype, I get that error.

So you should change your NpgsqlDBtType. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have the following table:

```
create table foo (
  bar integer
)
```

If you prepare an insert into the table as follows:

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into foo values (:BAR)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("BAR", NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
```

It's probably pretty obvious that this will throw an error:

```
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = "Hello";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

For the same reason this would throw an error:

```
insert into foo values ('Hello')
```

This will clearly work, as it's an integer all around:

```
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = 5;
```

But what you may not know is the following will all still work, since they are compatible datatypes:

```
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = 5M;
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = 5f;
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = (short)5;
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = (long)5;
```

However, even though PostgreSQL is tolerant enough to accept this in raw SQL:

```
insert into foo values ('5')
```

Npgsql 4 will throw the error you mentioned when you try to do this:

```
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = "5";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Interestingly, I'm pretty sure it worked with Npgsql 3.x, but I consider the error an improvement.

Since it is expecting a numeric datatype, the simple solution is to be sure any `.Value` you assign is also a numeric datatype, ideally an integer:

```
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(yourObject);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

With the standard warnings about error trapping and the use of `int.TryParse`.

From your code above it actually looks like you might be taking something that could already exist as an integer and convert it into a string.  If you do away with all that, you may find it works out of the box.  In any case, the `.Value` property needs to be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand your code sample above - you create and populate `parameter`, but then add a completely different instance of `NpgsqlParameter` to the comment.

However, the error message clearly says that you are trying to write a string as an integer. This happens when you set `NpgsqlParameter.Value` to a string value, but set its `NpgsqlDbType` to `Integer`. Either omit setting `NpgsqlDbType` altogether (Npgsql will usually infer the correct type from the value) or make sure they are properly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with the following code

```
  var utctime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  writer.Write(utctime, NpgsqlDbType.TimestampTz);
```

So basically you are converting utctime to string but while writing to database using type as Timestamp which is not a string. Therefore it throws error as the data is not compatible with the data type.

The fix is to not cast the utctime to string just use it as is. so working solution is

```
  var utctime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
  writer.Write(utctime, NpgsqlDbType.TimestampTz);
```